# Trip to Grand Canyon / Havasu Falls

Tags: planning, sightseeing, hiking, grand-canyon, waterfalls

I am currently trying to plan a trip to the Grand Canyon (never been!), and while there I would like to make the hike to Havasu falls.  Unfortunately, it is really hard - for me, at least - to find *current* information on how to do this; most of the articles/blogs about Havasu falls are almost ten years old!

So my questions are the following:

1. What is a good time to visit the Grand Canyon? I would prefer to avoid "busy" season (though I'm sure the Grand Canyon is always busy).
2. I will be traveling from NY; what is the best place to fly into / where should I stay to maximize the closeness / cost ratio?
3. How do I get to Havasu falls? I want to do the 10 mile hike, but do I need a guide? If so, where can I procure one? If not, how will I know where I'm going?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a long time since I did Havasu falls but I can at least answer #3--no guides needed.  The trail is obvious.  Note that there is a 2,500' elevation change on the hike, this isn't a walk in the park!

Beware that considerable advance booking is required as there are limited accommodations.  Doing it as a day trip isn't viable for most people.

The main airport is Phoenix, this is some hours away.  Flagstaff is a couple hours closer, Kingman is also in the area.  I can't address the economics of the options, it was always a road trip from Phoenix for me.

Comment: When you say advanced booking, you mean for hotels in the area? Or do you have to "reserve" hiking the trail? I read on a couple of sites it's a $20 fee to actually enter the trail.

Comment: @SteveD: I'm not aware of any reserving on the trail itself but I was never the one to organize it.  You do have to reserve campground space or hotel space.  Just showing up you'll find them full.

Comment: OK, perfect! One more small question: when you say the "trail is obvious", does that mean from a specific point? I mean, I know next to nothing about the Grand Canyon.  Are there multiple entrances/starting points?

Comment: @SteveD: I don't recall the trailhead situation but I think it's clear.  You can't miss the trail itself, I've walked much of it at night by full moonlight alone when I was feeling miserable.